# T4 template multiple outputs

Tags: c#, t4

I want to use another t4 template to give input instead of this.WriteLine("Hello, World!"); .Is that possible?

```
 <#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>

<#@ output extension="txt" #>
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>

Sample Content

<#    for(int i=7;i<9;i++){

        SampleTemplate template = new SampleTemplate();
        template.Output.File = @"SubFolder\SampleOutput"+i+".txt";
        template.Output.Project = @"..\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj";        
        template.Render();
    }
#>


<#+
    public class SampleTemplate : Template
    {
        public override string TransformText()
        {            
            this.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

            return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
        }
    }
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a T4 function that redirects the current template output to a file you specify - save this as SaveOutput.tt:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#

void SaveOutput(string outputFileName)
{
  string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
  string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, outputFileName);
  File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString()); 
  this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);
}

#>
```

And when generating your output code, call the function:

```
<#@ include file="SaveOutput.tt" #>
<#
    GenerateFile1();
    SaveOutput("File1.txt");  

    GenerateFile2();
    SaveOutput("File2.txt");
#>
<#
    void GenerateFile1()
    {
#>
This is file 1
<#
    }  

    void GenerateFile2()
    {
#>
This is file 2
<#+
    }
#>
```

Note: I took this code from [Oleg Sych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106206/oleg-sych)'s blog as he posted a now-dead link to his blog showing the steps required as an answer to this question. Since SO doesn't like link only answers, I re-posted the relevant code from that blogpost. You can find a copy of [his blogpost on the wayback machine here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160501025241/http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/). The only difference is that I have removed the '+' characters after each T4 code block starts - they don't appear to be necessary.